# Android ¿Sharedpreferences guarda null?

Tags: android, archivo, sharedpreferences

Buenas a todos!
Estoy haciendo una app usando Android Studio. Es muy simple, tiene un campo numérico para ingresar un `número de cliente` y un botón de `confirmar` que en base al número ingresado te trae los `puntos` de ese cliente. Estoy usando `SharedPreferences` para guardar el número de cliente y cada vez que inicia la app comprueba si hay un número de cliente guardado o no. En caso de que sí haya número, carga los puntos. El problema es que al cerrar la app y volver a iniciarla es como si se volviera `null` el valor de SharedPreferences. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal. Es la primera vez que uso SharedPreferences. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

PD: con el número de cliente 47, devuelve el valor 101. Al principio funciona. Pero al cerrar y abrir la app ya no.

Les dejo mi código:

```
public class Tab1_MisPuntos extends Fragment {

TextView tv_nroCliente;
EditText txt_IdCliente;
Button bConfirmar;
TextView tv_puntosCliente;

String type = "login";
String PREF_ID_CLIENTE = "";

ImageView img1;
ImageView img2;
ImageView img3;
ImageView img4;
ImageView img5;
ImageView img6;


@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_mispuntos, container, false);

    tv_nroCliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nroCliente);
    txt_IdCliente = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_IdCliente);
    bConfirmar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bConfirmar);
    tv_puntosCliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_puntosCliente);

    img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img2);
    img3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img3);
    img4 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img4);
    img5 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img5);
    img6 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img6);



    if(SaveSharedPreference.getNroCliente(this.getContext()).length() == 0)
    {
        //Seguir normal
    }
    else
    {
        //Obtener puntos
        new BackgroundWorker(getContext(),tv_puntosCliente, txt_IdCliente, bConfirmar).execute(type, PREF_ID_CLIENTE);
    }

    //Boton Confirmar.
    bConfirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (txt_IdCliente.getText().toString().equals("")){
                //ALERTDIALOG "Por favor, ingrese un nro de cliente."
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage(R.string.alertDialogMensaje1)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //Aceptar
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            else {
                PREF_ID_CLIENTE = txt_IdCliente.getText().toString();
                //Obtener puntos desde urlPuntos + idCliente;
                SaveSharedPreference.setNroCliente(getContext(), PREF_ID_CLIENTE);
                new BackgroundWorker(getContext(),tv_puntosCliente, txt_IdCliente, bConfirmar).execute(type, PREF_ID_CLIENTE);
            }
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

Clase SharedPreferences:

```
class SaveSharedPreference {

static final String PREF_ID_CLIENTE= "NroCliente";

static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}

public static void setNroCliente(Context ctx, String nroCliente)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_ID_CLIENTE, nroCliente);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getNroCliente(Context ctx)
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_ID_CLIENTE, "");
}
```

Clase BackgroundWorker

```
class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private final TextView tv_puntosCliente;
private final Button bConfirmar;
private final EditText txt_IdCliente;


Context context;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx, TextView tv_puntosCliente, EditText txt_IdCliente, Button bConfirmar) {
    context = ctx;
    this.tv_puntosCliente = tv_puntosCliente;
    this.bConfirmar = bConfirmar;
    this.txt_IdCliente = txt_IdCliente;
}
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private String PREF_ID_CLIENTE = "";
private String type = "";


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    type = params[0];
    PREF_ID_CLIENTE = params[1];

    String urlPuntos = "http://myweb.com/app/clubapp.php?i=0&c="+PREF_ID_CLIENTE;

    if(type.equals("login")) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlPuntos);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode(" ","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(PREF_ID_CLIENTE,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);

            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();

    if (result.equals("")){
        //ALERTDIALOG "Por favor, ingrese un nro de cliente."
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.alertDialogMensaje2)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Aceptar
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    else {
        //Puntos
        tv_puntosCliente.setText(result);
        txt_IdCliente.setText(SaveSharedPreference.getNroCliente(this.context), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        txt_IdCliente.setEnabled(false);
        bConfirmar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

EDIT:
Lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera:
Al pasarle el parámetro al BackgroundWorker, en vez de pasarle PREF_ID_CLIENTE que por defecto inicializa como vacío, le pasé esto: SaveSharedPreference.getNroCliente(getContext());

Y funciona bien. Gracias a todos por responder!.

Comment: ¿tienes rooteado el móvil?, para que verifiques con un explorador de archivos haber que esta guardando en el xml de las preferencias

Comment: Te conectas a un WebService si comprendo bien, para que usar sharedPreferend ?

Comment: Has comprobado que el preferencesManager siempre te devuelva el mismo fichero? Prueba si no creando unas sharedPreferences pasandole una clave

Comment: @AlvaroFabianM No lo tengo rooteado.

Comment: @AshleyG. Si, obtengo los puntos a través de un php. Pensé en usar SharedPref para que se guarde el número/id del cliente, ya que es un número largo y lo tengan que poner una única vez, ya que nadie se lo va a acordar.

Comment: y porque no solo usas una consulta para tu BD donde guerdas tus puntos y los muestras al usuario

Comment: @AshleyG. Porque es necesario que el usuario escriba su ID de cliente. Si no, no tendría forma de ver sus puntos.

Comment: El ID es el único identificador único para cada usuario por ende no se puede repetir. En rigor el usuario no debe escribir su ID solo debería iniciar sesión por ejemplo ... Aunque el ID Peoria ser un RUT y con ello sería más práctico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código de tu clase para guardar y obtener los datos es correcto.

Pero en tu clase Tab1_MisPuntos  al iniciar estas definiendo un valor vació de `PREF_ID_CLIENTE` el cual sobrescribe la preferencia.

```
public class Tab1_MisPuntos extends Fragment {

...
...
String PREF_ID_CLIENTE = "";
...
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_mispuntos, container, false);   

    if(SaveSharedPreference.getNroCliente(this.getContext()).length() == 0)
    {
        //Seguir normal
    }
    else
    {
        //Obtener puntos
        new BackgroundWorker(getContext(),tv_puntosCliente, txt_IdCliente, bConfirmar).execute(type, PREF_ID_CLIENTE);
    }

....
```

---

Noto que usas la variable PREF_ID_CLIENTE como key de la preferencia en la clase `SaveSharedPreference` pero también en otras partes de tu código, te sugiero no usar esta misma variable para que no te confundas.

Comment: Tal vez estoy equivocado, pero, no es necesario inicializar la variable? Creo que si solamente defino "String PREF_ID_CLIENTE;" de esta manera, me da error. Y cómo podría usar otra variable?.

Comment: Puedes declararla también como private String PREF_ID_CLIENTE = ""; Pero me refiero a que al iniciar y pasar por onCreate() no tiene ningún valor al pasar por el AsyncTask ".execute(type, PREF_ID_CLIENTE);".

Comment: Entonces, qué podría hacer? Porque la idea que tenía era justamente que al pasarle la variable no pierda el valor.

Comment: Bueno, lo pude solucionar Jorgesys. Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No es muy aconsejable usar el `getDefaultSharedPreferences` en su lugar, intenta con el siguiente código:

```
private final static String preferences_key="MyDB";

getSharedPreferences(preferences_key,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```